# Declaring variable in recursive function C++

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I wish to declare a variable `w` inside a recursive function. I have to declare it as `f(a)` (some function of `a`) where `a` is a parameter of the function. The problem is that the function is recursive and `w` changes value every time the recursive function is called (since `a` changes)

Is there a way to do keep `w` fixed to its first initialization?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int a)
{ 
    if(a==1) return 0;
    // int w = f(a);
    //...some more lines of code that use 'w'
    // eg. return foo(a - 1);
}
```

Comment: It would help if we knew *what language you're working in* (hint: tags) and if you perhaps included your current work as either code or pseudo-code to illustrate what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm using C, I can even use C++.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Please explain to us the exact meaning of a 'constant' that 'changes value every time [the] function is called'.

Comment: @EJP for eg. `function(int a){ if(a==0)return 1; const int x=a*7; cout<<x; return function(a-1);}` here I want x to be a constant equal to 7 times initial value of 'a'

Comment: If the value changes depending on function parameters, then it isn't really a constant, is it?

Comment: @Lundin but I want some variable(which is a function of parameter) to remain unchanged even when parameters change

Comment: How can x be constant if it  depends on the variable "a", that is not constant ? You can't declare it as const

Comment: @Val_MagicStar I meant constant in a sense that its value doesn't change on each function call, I got the correct implementation by using `static int x=7*a`

Comment: @ab123 ok, in this way is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to implement a variable that keeps its state between function calls is to use the static keyword.

```
int AddOne_Static(void) {
    static int a;
    
    a++;
    
    return a;
}

int AddOne(void) {
    int a;
    
    a++;
    
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", AddOne_Static());
    printf("%d\n", AddOne_Static());
    printf("%d\n", AddOne_Static());
    
    printf("%d\n", AddOne());
    printf("%d\n", AddOne());
    printf("%d\n", AddOne());
}
```

The Output will be:

```
1
2
3

1
1
1
```

This is a much cleaner way of declaring a variable that will keep its value between calls than a global which will also pollute the global namespace unnecessarily.

Comment: Where will I initialise 'a'?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, they are automatically initialized to zero if not stated and is not overwritten if the value is stated multiple times:

http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html

Explains this a little more clearly

Comment: @GMoney `a` in `AddOne` is uninitialised.

Comment: @LogicStuff According to 6.7.8/10 in the C99 standard [link](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), the value will be set explicitly to zero as it is an arithmetic type.

Comment: @GMoney *"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate"* - `a` in `AddOne` has automatic storage duration. And please refer to C++ standard when answering C++ questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a constant if you want to make 'w' a constant. Defining a constant may differ according to the language.

In your case, you cannot use w as a constant since the value of w is changed when the function gets recursive.

But if you need a constant which does not change its value over the runtime of the program, then, you definitely can define a constant globally or inside the function and use the value.

Hope you got your answer. :)

Comment: There should be no need for "globals". Simply declare a  `static const` inside the function.

Comment: @Lundin  - that worked!